Understanding the concept of "co-": is it really a complement?
I don't quite understand the concept of complement in complexity theory. I don't understand the connection between this concept of complement and the complement from set theory. As the Wikipedia article says:

<...> the complement of a decision problem is the decision problem
resulting from reversing the yes and no answers. Equivalently, if we define decision problems as sets of finite strings, then the complement of this set over some fixed domain is its complement problem. For example, one important problem is whether a number is a prime number. Its
complement is to determine whether a number is a composite number (a
number which is not prime). Here the domain of the complement is the
set of all integers exceeding one. <...>

I don't understand this "over some fixed domain" phrase. As far as I could imagine this implies that for each language $L$ we should have its own proper superset ("superlanguage") $\tilde{L}$, and the complexity theory complement $\bar{L}$ is defined as $\bar{L} = \tilde{L} \setminus L$? In case of the language $L$ of prime numbers $\tilde{L}$ would be the subset of $\Sigma^*$ ($\Sigma$ is our alphabet) representing all natural numbers encoded by some previously fixed way of encoding natural numbers with the symbols from $\Sigma$. But I haven't come across such an idea in any source.
Or the complement language $\bar{L}$ is just $\bar{L} = \Sigma^* \setminus L$? But in this case if, for instance, $L$ again represents the set of all prime numbers, the complement language (set) $\bar{L}$ would contain not only all of the composite numbers (encoded by words from $\Sigma^*$) but all the words (elements of $\Sigma^*$) that cannot be recognized as a properly encoded natural number (elements of SAT language, for example).
Thank you in advance for your reply.

A language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ and the complement of a language is the complement in the set-theoretic sense. You're making this more complicated than it is.

Yes, the complement of the language of valid encodings of prime numbers is the language of invalid encodings and valid encodings of composite numbers. You can get rid of this problem by picking a bijective encoding of the natural numbers.

The set theoretic definition (without the "super-language") is cleaner and more standard. But most of the time it shouldn't matter too much, and folks are definitely sloppy about handling "invalid" inputs properly.
But let's start with the standard definition. For a language $L$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$
$$\overline L := \Sigma^* \setminus L.$$
Consider your alternate definition relative to a super-language $M$ with $L \subseteq M \subseteq \Sigma^*$:
$$\overline L_M := M \setminus L.$$
Now for complexity-theoretic arguments, this shouldn't matter, as long as $M$ can be "easily" decided (relative to the classes you are analyzing) and the class has "strong enough" closure properties. Instead of arguing this in the abstract, let's take an example.
Assume $L \in \text{NP}$ i.e. $\overline L \in \text{co-NP}$. We want to show that $\overline L_M \in \text{co-NP}$ as well; note
$$\overline{\overline L_M} = \Sigma^* \setminus (M \setminus L) = L \cup \overline M.$$
Assuming $M \in \text{P}$ then we can conclude by closure properties that $L \cup \overline M \in \text{NP}$ as desired.
Note: for the sake of this argument we can even take $M \in \text{co-NP}$ but then the converse doesn't hold.
